# insertando en mysql desde PHP

Tags: php, mysql

despues de muchos intentos, no me queda mas remedio que recurrir a los que Saben....
intento enviar un INSERT a mysql desde PHP de esta forma....

```
$sql="INSERT INTO vacaciones (idTrabajador, FechaInicio, FechaFinal, TotalDias, firmado, impreso,documento) VALUES ('".$operario."' ,'".$fechaI."' ,'".$fechaF."' ,'".$value."' ,0,0,'".$documento.".pdf')";
```

un echo en PHP para confirmar el resultado de $sql me devuelve esto:

> SQL INSERT INTO vacaciones (idTrabajador, FechaInicio, FechaFinal,
> TotalDias, firmado, impreso,documento) VALUES ('1' ,'2021-01-25'
> ,'2021-01-26' ,'2' ,0,0,'1292850.pdf')

este resultado lo ejecuto directamente en Mysql y todo perfecto...

desde PHP, solo inserta "1292850", la extension '.pdf' no aparece....

Por que???

Comment: Gracias...el campo documento debe estar bien, porque como digo en la pregunta, si lo hago directamente en mysql, si funciona, desde PHP, solo inserta el nombre de archivo, no la extension...

Comment: Es porque estás concatenado mal en el documento `".$documento.".pdf')";` solo estás enviando documento pero no estás agregando el `.pdf`

Comment: @ELEAFISL mi mayor duda es ¿por qué agregas de ese modo la extensión del archivo?, en realidad debes componer tu consulta asi?

Comment: Daniel, la consulta la veo con un 'echo', y el resultado lo ejecuo directamente en mysql y funciona,

Comment: @ELEAFI podrías poner el código de cómo lo estás insertando directamente en mysql?